# How to display all values from firebase database and separate each one by a CSS border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know how to return each firebase value, each inside of a CSS border.
So I have the code to connect and everything. But I want to get all the values inside of "Post". Take a look at the code:

```js
var text = firebase.database().ref("text/");

function post(){
var newPost = document.getElementById('newPost').value;
var p = document.getElementById('p');
p.innerHTML = newPost;

      text.set ({
   Post: {
     hertext: newPost
     
   }
    
   
});
}


text.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey) {
  var newPlayer = data.val();
var p = document.getElementById('p');
p.innerHTML = newPlayer.hertext;
});
```

```html
<textarea id = "newPost"></textarea>

<button onclick = "post();">Post</button>

<p id = "p"></p>
```

But how do I put more than just one value into the database? With the code I have now, the latest value just replaces the value before it. How do I make it so it makes and displays a list of items, not just the last one added? And once they are all displayed on the screen, is there any way to make each value displayed separately with a CSS border around it? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply separate CSS styling to each `Post` node from the database, you'll need to make sure that each `Post` ends up in a separate element in your HTML.

The easiest way to do that is to generate a new HTML element, each time `child_added` is fired:

```
text.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey) {
  var newPlayer = data.val();
  var p = document.getElementById('p');
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = newPlayer.hertext
  p.appendChild(span);
});
```

Now you can apply separate CSS styling to each `span` element under your `id` element.

---

If you want to **store** multiple values in the database, you'll need to add its `push()` method instead of `set()`:

```
text.push({
    hertext: newPost  
})
```

This generates a new so-called push ID under `/text` where it then stores your new structure. I've removed the `Post` wrapper, as I think that may be no longer needed.

Comment: That helps, but the new value still replaces the last.